# ServiceStack Ormlite - Postgres serializing Date property with MaxDate to JsonB

Tags: postgresql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a complex object which I save to a JsonB field in postgres using Ormlite.
One of the property is a DateTime and is set to DateTime.Max.

Retrieving the object from Postgres the DateTime property value is set to DateTime.Min value

```
01/01/0001 00:00:00
```

Not sure if this is a bug with Ormlite or the json serializer.

Code snippet to replicate

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var item = new LicenseCheckTemp();
        item.Body = new CheckHistory();
        item.Body.List.Add(new ItemHistory() {AddedOn = DateTime.MaxValue, Note = "Test"});

        var factory = GetFactory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PostgresConnectionString"]);
        using (var db = factory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            db.CreateTableIfNotExists<LicenseCheckTemp>();
            db.Save(item);
        }

        using (var db = factory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
          var items =  db.Select<LicenseCheckTemp>();

            foreach (var licenseCheck in items.OrderBy(x=>x.Id))
            {
                if (licenseCheck.Body != null && licenseCheck.Body.List.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var itemHistory in licenseCheck.Body.List)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{itemHistory.AddedOn} :  Note {itemHistory.Note}");
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();


    }


    public static IDbConnectionFactory GetFactory(string connection)
    {
        var factory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connection,
           PostgreSqlDialect.Provider);

        factory.DialectProvider.NamingStrategy = new OrmLiteNamingStrategyBase();

        return factory;
    }
}

public class LicenseCheckTemp
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [CustomField("json")]
    public CheckHistory Body { get; set; }
}

public class CheckHistory
{
    public List<ItemHistory> List { get; set; } = new List<ItemHistory>();
}

public class ItemHistory
{
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: please post the exact source code that shows the issue.

Comment: Hi mythz, added code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst OrmLite doesn't have explicit support for PostgreSQL JSON DataTypes, OrmLite's existing JSON serialization of ComplexType properties should allow this to work naturally as seen below:

I've added an example of [this test in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/b2e34c02c57a1eb226bf4516ff154d42efd01ffd):

```
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.NamingStrategy = new OrmLiteNamingStrategyBase();

var item = new LicenseCheckTemp();
item.Body = new CheckHistory();
item.Body.List.Add(new ItemHistory { AddedOn = DateTime.MaxValue, Note = "Test" });

using (var db = OpenDbConnection())
{
    db.DropAndCreateTable<LicenseCheckTemp>();
    db.GetLastSql().Print();
    db.Save(item);
}

using (var db = OpenDbConnection())
{
    var items = db.Select<LicenseCheckTemp>();
    items.PrintDump();

    foreach (var licenseCheck in items.OrderBy(x => x.Id))
    {
        if (licenseCheck.Body != null && licenseCheck.Body.List.Any())
        {
            foreach (var itemHistory in licenseCheck.Body.List)
            {
                $"{itemHistory.AddedOn} :  Note {itemHistory.Note}".Print();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is working as expected, i.e. it Prints out:

```
CREATE TABLE "LicenseCheckTemp" 
(
  "Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  "Body" json NULL 
); 

[
    {
        Id: 1,
        Body: 
        {
            List: 
            [
                {
                    Note: Test,
                    AddedOn: 9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999-05:00
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM :  Note Test
```

Showing CreateTable creating a "json" type for Body property with the row being serialized and returned fully populated.

Can't repro why it's not working for you, are you using the latest v4.0.54 release of OrmLite? Does it work with a smaller DateTime? (perhaps Max DateTime in your TimeZone exceeds what your PgSql configured instance supports).

Comment: I'm using the 4.0.54 release with PostgreSQL 9.5.  Looking at your print out the date stored in PostgreSQL doesn't look the same  {"List":[{"Note":"Test","AddedOn":"\/Date(253402300800000-0000)\/"}]} . I assumed the way the date was stored was standard, is there any other settings I can set to get the date like your output?

Comment: @laitang There is no standard way to store dates in JSON, ServiceStack.Text defaults to WCF JSON Dates. You change the default DateFormat using `JsConfig.DateHandler = ...` and any of the [DateHandler Enum Values](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/6f74693750b70f53c78b44151e330c676c2e7944/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs#L1293)

Comment: Thank you! That worked changing to JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601 solved the problem.